# Why use tuples in Finger Trees vs Linked Lists etc

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, functional-programming

Regarding finger trees, as seen in [this paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf) and mentioned in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/02/12/immutability-in-c-part-eleven-a-working-double-ended-queue.aspx) by Eric Lippert.

I do not understand why an explicit tuple arrangement is used, as opposed to some sort of linked list structure for each finger. That is, why do we define `One(x), Two(x, y), Three(x, y, z), Four(x, y, z, a)` and not just have a less optimal deque object and do `LessOptimalDeque.AddLeft(x)`?

Is it somehow slower? I mean, even though you could use some data structure that re-uses the memory of some nodes/groups of nodes?

In the paper, it's even mentioned:

> Exercise 1. In the above presentation, we represented digits as lists for simplicity.
>   A more accurate and efficient implementation would use the type

```
data Digit a = One a  
| Two a a
| Three a a a
| Four a a a a
```

> Rework the above denitions to use this denition of Digit.

I don't know why it's more efficient though. Is it only something relevant to the functional language the author was using, and otherwise could also be done using the data structures I proposed above?

**Edit**
[image]

What about implementing the finger like this?

Comment: This is saving you lots of allocations (basically halving it, or more). It is not insignificant.

Comment: Is it? I mean, it seems to me, `Three -> Four` conversion involves creating an object, and populating its four fields from scratch. You get to make two objects like this if you're going down a level. At least two objects. If you use a data structure, such as a tree-based deque of some sort, you might well populate fewer fields. Is the efficiency that clear-cut?

Comment: In a functional style, going from three to four always requires allocation, because you can't change anything. You need to remake to entire path up to the root. What's different though is that the objects kept alive are less than with some kind of per-node list.

Comment: No, you can avoid some allocation while still ensuring immutability. Imagine splitting a balances binary tree with depth n at the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why this is more efficient in Haskell:

```
data Digit a
           = One a  
           | Two a a
           | Three a a a
           | Four a a a a
```

than this (the obvious encoding of a vector):

```
data List a = One a
            | Many a (List a) -- a linked list of at least one element.
```

we can observe the heap structure necessary to allocate a `Digit` vs a `List`.

```
Four 'x' 'y' 'z' 'd'
```

vs

```
Many 'x' (Many 'y' (Many 'z' (One 'd')))
```

In the former case, we save 3 constructors. In the latter we are forced to allocate additional heap objects for the (possibly infinite) tail of the structure. In general, the `Digit` representation will allocate *O(n-1)* fewer heap cells, as the size of the structure is encoded in the outermost constructor. We can also determine the size in *O(1)* as a result.

Comment: I see, thank you :) What about my implementation, involving a strange tree-like structure?

Comment: @GregRos about your edit: 1st variant: start with 1 nodes, 2 new nodes created (3 nodes total); 2nd variant: start with 3 nodes, 1 new node created (4 nodes total). Plus, the access to `a`, `b`, `c` is slower than to `d`.